# google pie chart dynamic with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I want to make dynamic generation of google pie chart with provided library of them.

I have this code for get data from mysql:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM mybase WHERE name = '$name' ";

        $mysqli = new mysqli();
        $mysqli->connect('localhost', 'blabla', 'blabla', 'blabla');
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //here I cant figure out how to make data in format for pie chart
        }
```

I need to get this data to Java script. Seen x times means how many times it is in database listed:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Seen x times'],
          ['somenamefrommysql',     11],
          ['somenamefrommysql',      2],
          ['somenamefrommysql',  2],
          ['somenamefrommysql', 2],
          ['somenamefrommysql',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your HTML & JS are producing a good pie chart, then why don't you use your PHP code to generate the JS code dynamically? More specifically, you have to generate the `data` variable, which is just a string from PHP's point of view. On the other hand, if you have tons of data, perhaps this is not the best approach, and you may need to use some fancy AJAX calls...

Answer (score 0):

A DataTable can be created from pure JSON, so if you can get your PHP script to return the results as a JSON object in the format that it requires then it will work.

See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable